# Actualizar datos

Tags: php, mysql

No me actualiza los datos y no se por que me podrías orientar cual es mi error, este es mi código:

```
<?php

session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lista"); 
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
$agencia = $_POST['agencia'];
$depa =  $_POST['departamento'];
$area =  $_POST['area'];
$nombre =  $_POST['nombre'];
$ext     =  $_POST['extencion'];    

$sql = $mysqli->query("update lista set id='$id', agencia='$agencia', departamento=$depa, area='$area', nombre='$nombre',extencion='$ext' where id='$id'");
?>  

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript"> 
     alert("Contacto Actualizado"); 
</SCRIPT> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=listar.php">
```

Comment: La sintaxis está mal, es id=' ". $id . " ' " y así con todo, te faltan los  puntos para concatenar y cerrar las comillas dobles y volver abrir con las simples para poner los ' de mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vi varios detalles en tu código y te paso el siguiente script; pruébalo y quedo pendiente de tus comentarios:

```
<?php

session_start();

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lista"); 
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conexion->connect_error);
} 

$id = $_POST['id']; $agencia = $_POST['agencia']; $depa = $_POST['departamento']; $area = $_POST['area']; $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; $ext = $_POST['extencion'];

$sql = "UPDATE lista SET id='".$id."', agencia='".$agencia."', departamento='".$depa."', area='".$area."', nombre='".$nombre."',extencion='".$ext."' where id='".$id"'";

if($conexion->query($sql)){
    echo "Modificado con éxito";
}else{
    echo "No modificado";
}
```

Como puedes notar la sintaxis para tus variables debe ser `'".$variable."'`

También te recomiendo que tu variable que almacena la conexión no la nombres igual que el `driver` que estas usando es decir `mysqli`, te lo cambie por `$conexion` y debería seguir funcionando